# When trying to create an account number, I get an IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want that when creating an account number, the owner of the account be the current logged-in user.

I have read about foreign key constraints but do not know what constraint the CustomUser class is having to conflict the creation of an account number.

I have tried setting `on_delete` to `CASCADE` but still it throws the `IntegrityError`

Please help. Thanks.

My `models.py`

```py
class CustomUser(TrackingModel, AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin):
    GENDER = (
        ("F", "Female"),
        ("M", "Male"),
        ("NS", "Not Specified"),
    )

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=GENDER)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [
        "phone",
    ]

    @property
    def token(self):
        token = jwt.encode(
            {
                "username": self.username,
                "email": self.email,
                "exp": datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=24),
            },
            settings.SECRET_KEY,
            algorithm="HS256",
        )
        return token

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Accountnumber(TrackingModel):
    TYPE = (
        ("momo", "MTN Mobile Money"),
        ("om", "Orange Money"),
        ("visa", "Visa"),
        ("paypal", "Paypal"),
    )

    number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=9999)
    type = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=TYPE,
        null=True,
        default="momo",
    )
    customuser = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser,
        related_name="acc_no_user",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    cdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    enddate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    transactions = models.ForeignKey(
        "Transaction",
        related_name="acc_no_transactions",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        default="2",
    )
    balance = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        default=00,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.number
```

My `views.py`:

```py
class CreateAccountnumberAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = AccountnumberSerializer
    permission_classes = {
        IsAuthenticated,
    }

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

My `serializers.py`:

```py
class AccountnumberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Accountnumber
        fields = (
            "number",
            "type",
            "cdate",
            "enddate",
            "transactions",
            "balance",
        )
```

My stacktrace shows at `perform_create()` at `views.py`:

```
Internal Server Error: /api/v1/wallet/v1/account
Traceback (most recent call last):      
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Dev\API\grand\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 98, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)        
sqlite3.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):      
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Dev\API\grand\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)    
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Dev\API\grand\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)     
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Dev\API\grand\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)   
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Dev\API\grand\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Dev\API\grand\.venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Dev\API\grand\.venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)  
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Dev\API\grand\.venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Dev\API\grand\.venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Dev\API\grand\.venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\generics.py", line 190, in post
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Dev\API\grand\.venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 19, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)     
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Dev\API\grand\wallet\views.py", line 69, in perform_create
    return serializer.save(customuser=self.request.user)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Dev\API\grand\.venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 
212, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Dev\API\grand\.venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 
962, in create
    instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Dev\API\grand\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), 
name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Dev\API\grand\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 514, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Dev\API\grand\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 806, 
in save
    self.save_base(
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Dev\API\grand\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 857, 
in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Dev\API\grand\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1000, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Dev\API\grand\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1041, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Dev\API\grand\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), 
name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Dev\API\grand\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1434, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)        
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Dev\API\grand\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1632, in execute_sql
    self.connection.ops.fetch_returned_insert_columns(
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Dev\API\grand\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\operations.py", line 208, in fetch_returned_insert_columns
    return cursor.fetchone()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Dev\API\grand\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 97, in inner
    with self:
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Dev\API\grand\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Dev\API\grand\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 98, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)        
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN 
KEY constraint failed
[13/Jan/2023 04:19:51] "POST /api/v1/wallet/v1/account HTTP/1.1" 500 183218
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All through, comments from my search for the answer have been that the `IntegrityError` of `ForeignKey constriant failed` mostly arises from the fact that you are trying to use a foreign key that does not yet exist and it was my case.

When creating an account number, I asked in my `models.py` that the field `transactions` be linked to the `Transaction` table foreign key WHICH DID NOT EXIST YET.

I, therefore, replaced the `transaction` field from referring to a `ForeignKey` to making it a `CharField` where I used the choices option and it worked.

Thanks, @Pavel Vergeev for editing my code

Thanks, @Ridape for pointing out an error which turns out was not the reason for the IntegrityError I was facing.

Answer (score 0):

In your `perform_create` function you do the following:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    return serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

So you're saving the `user` variable to the user that made this request. That is fine, however, in your `Accountnumber` model, you store the user in the `customuser` field, not the `user` field.

Try to set your `perform_create` function to the following:

```
 def perform_create(self, serializer):
    return serializer.save(customuser=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Ridape for pointing out that mistake. I corrected it but it still throws the same IntegrityError.